# Insertar un array PostgreSQL de tipo compuesto desde PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Como dice el título estoy buscando la manera de insertar desde **php** un array (PostgreSQL), el cual es un tipo compuesto.

Edito que veo que me he explicado muy mal:

Pongo de ejemplo este caso:

```
create type persona as (
    nombre text,
    apellidos text,
    dni int
);

create table casa (
    familia persona[]
);
```

Quiero lograr una inserción similar a cualquiera de los siguientes ejemplos mediante una consulta desde PHP (PDO):

```
insert into casa values (
    array [
        ('NombreFamiliar1', 'ApellidosFamiliar1', 012345678)::persona,
        ('NombreFamiliar2', 'ApellidosFamiliar2', 012345678)::persona
    ]
);


insert into casa values (
    '{ "( \"NombreFamiliar1\", \"ApellidosFamiliar1\", 012345678 )", "( \"NombreFamiliar2\", \"ApellidosFamiliar2\", 012345678 )" }'
);
```

Comment: no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero postgreSQL te permite crear campos tipo json no se si eso es lo que buscas

Comment: Puedes convertir el array a JSON e insertarlo. [Aquí puedes revisar la documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html) sobre el tipo de dato JSON y cómo funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me auto respondo, no sé por qué no me funcionaba antes pero de la siguiente manera funciona, no obstante para introducir valores numéricos no sé si sería la forma correcta, lo he intentado con campos de tipo enteros (int) y funciona también (supongo que internamente pgsql hace la conversión).

```
$ejemplo1 = "{\"(valor1,valor2)\"}";
$ejemplo2 = "{\"(" . $valor1 . "," . $valor2 . ")\"}";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into tabla values(default, :campo1, :campo2, :tipoCompuestoArray);");
$stmt->execute( array('campo1'=>$valor, 'campo2'=>$valor, 'tipoCompuestoArray'=>$ejemploX );
```